# Mover um site grande Wordpress próprio para o Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress

Eu gostaria de alguma ajuda para mover um site grande de 11 anos com armazenamento de 38 Gb para o wordpress.com. Encontrei algumas instruções no banco de dados de ajuda oficial, mas não tenho certeza se podemos segui-las sem perder dados.

Comment: Para toda operação que for fazer é importante você ter um backup do seu banco de dados e da sua aplicação. Tendo isso em mãos você não perderá seus dados caso ocorra algum problema. Os únicos pontos de atenção que eu vejo é comprar o plano de hospedagem adequado e tomar cuidado para não comprometer seu rankeamento no google (SEO). Existem alguns [plugins](https://www.wpsuperstars.net/top-wordpress-migration-plugins/) que podem te ajudar nessa tarefa.

Comment: adicionei outra solução, veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: O wordpress possui uma ferramenta para fazer este procedimento, veja: https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Import_Screen

Comment: o site é muito grande e não é possivel usar a ferramenta de importação pois ela dá timeout dado o volume de dados e visto que hoje ele está em um servidor compartilhado e não tenho acesso a quaisquer mudança de configuração do mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Se o website tiver um painel de controlo do gênero **CPanel** pode fazer um backup através do mesmo. Nesse backup terá a BD, emails e tudo incluso na pasta public_html.
Depois bastará importar o backup no servidor de destino e neste caso o "Cpanel" irá fazer a reposição do backup.

Caso o servidor de destino não tenha um painel de controlo o melhor será utilizar o mysql em modo cli e importar o banco por aí.

Para isso terá de ter acesso por ssh ao servidor.

Aqui vai um exemplo de importação da base de dados:
`mysql -h nomedoservidor -u utilizador -p basedados < ficheiro.sql`

Para todos os outros ficheiros (public_html, entre outros) pode facilmente transferir-los por FTP.

**Outra solução:**

Existe um plugin para wordpress que gera um ficheiro de backup para facilmente importado em outra instalação do wordpress.

Plugin: [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

O funcionamento do plugin é bastante simples, basta instalar o plugin no site fazer backup e depois criar um nova instalação do wordpress no servidor de destino e importar o ficheiro de backup gerado anteriormente. É bastante simples, mas penso que a partir de um certo volume de informação o plugin requer uma versão paga ou algo do genero. Agora vai de acordo com as suas necessidades verificar se vale a pena comprar essa versão.

Tenho utilizado este plugin para diversos sites pois ele permite fazer a mudança de um dominio de teste para o dominio final, o próprio plugin reenscreve os urls para os que desejar.

Comment: Vou tentar a solução do plugin e retorno para dar feedback.